# Parsing html files on Azure

Tags: c#, parsing, azure

I have code that parses 100 to 200 html webpages using `HtmlAgilityPack` every hour. I am collecting the parsed data and I am making an xml file which would then be consumed by users.

Now I want to move this code to Azure. Would it be possible to parse websites on Windows azure? If so: what kind of service provided by Azure should I use?

I am not familiar with Azure. Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure offers you a couple of solutions:

IaaS

- IaaS or Infrastructure as a Service. This means that you get the infrastructure from Azure and that you can host your own virtual machine on it. This does require you to maintain the server yourself but you get full flexibility.
- PaaS or Platform as a Service. This not only gives you a VM to run your code on but also an operating system that is automatically maintained for you. This is what Azure is really about and what you should aim for.

When creating a PaaS application you can choose for a regular website or for a cloud service. A cloud service contains roles, web roles and worker roles. Web roles are regular IIS hosted websites. Worker roles are the Azure equivalent of a Windows service.

In your case I would look at [worker roles](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/common-tasks/create-web-and-worker-roles/). They can run continually and are ideal for exeucting scheduled operations. From your worker role you can access [Azure Blob storage](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/) to store the XML files that you create. Those files can be exposed to external users in a secure way.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure is a *hosting* environment. According to what kind of project you created, you may be looking for a  [Cloud Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/cloud-services/), where you can just host any code you've written.